# How do I sort this hash in Rails

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I need to sort this hash by distance. I'll also need to pull all of the zip_codes out of the hash.

```
{ "zip_codes" =>
  [
    { "zip_code"=>"80504", "distance"=>3.874, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
    { "zip_code"=>"80501", "distance"=>0, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
    { "zip_code"=>"80502", "distance"=>0.508, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
    { "zip_code"=>"80533", "distance"=>3.661, "city"=>"Hygiene", "state"=>"CO" }
  ]
}
```

For the first problem, sort_by seems to be what I need to do, but I haven't come up with a solution.

Comment: what do you expect the end result to be?

Comment: A data structure sorted ascending by distance.

Comment: And what does that data structure look like?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I need to sort this hash by distance." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `sort_by` is the way to go. You only need to access the array before actually sorting.

Assuming that hash is a variable called `h`:

```
h["zip_codes"].sort_by { |item| item['distance'] }

# the result:

[
  {"zip_code"=>"80501", "distance"=>0, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO"},
  {"zip_code"=>"80502", "distance"=>0.508, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO"},
  {"zip_code"=>"80533", "distance"=>3.661, "city"=>"Hygiene", "state"=>"CO"},
  {"zip_code"=>"80504", "distance"=>3.874, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO"}
]
```

If you want to get only the zip codes, you can `map` the result, like this:

```
h["zip_codes"].sort_by { |item| item['distance'] }.map { |item| item['zip_code'] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `sort_by` to sort and `.map` to get all `zip codes`.

```
 hash = { "zip_codes" =>
          [
            { "zip_code"=>"80504", "distance"=>3.874, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
            { "zip_code"=>"80501", "distance"=>0, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
            { "zip_code"=>"80502", "distance"=>0.508, "city"=>"Longmont", "state"=>"CO" },
            { "zip_code"=>"80533", "distance"=>3.661, "city"=>"Hygiene", "state"=>"CO" }
          ]
        }
```

1. Sorting based on distance

   `hash["zip_codes"].sort_by { |k| k["distance"] }`
2. To get all the zip code

   `hash["zip_codes"].map{|k| k["zip_code"]}`